# Spell Checker not working in Libre Office 6.0

Tags: 18.04, libreoffice

I am using Libre Office 6.0.7.3 on Ubuntu 18.04 and I cannot get spellchecking to work.  When I follow the suggestions for earlier releases of Libre Office they do not work.  Specifically I click on Tools/Language/For All Text in Writer it does not show any language as selected.  So I click on English Canada and the menu item closes immediately.  When I click on For All Text again the menu item still does not show English Canada as selected.  I would show a screenshot but libreoffice interferes with the keyboard shortcuts for taking a screenshot.  I NEED to select the language in order for spellcheck to work so how do I convince LibreOffice to use the language I am trying to select?

Manage languages under system settings shows both English Canada and English US as installed
[image: System Language Settings]

I have tried to follow the suggestion to select a bit of text and then go to Tools/Language.  This discussion does not permit including images in comments so I am putting the resulting image here:

[image]

I cannot select ANY of the languages in the selection list for Text Language. When I do the dialog immediately re-displays [None].

[image]

And the System Language management dialog says:

[image]

I am getting desperate.  I really need to know how to get spell checking working on this system.  How do I attract the attention of somebody who has actually worked on this code?

I am looking deeper into the hierarchy of dialogs:  At Tools/ Language/ More I see:

[image]

Note that I am so desperate to get any kind of spellcheck that I have switched the default system language to Amurikan.  UND IT STIL WIL NOUGHT CHEQUE MI SPELIN.

I am also annoyed that the date acceptance pattern is invalid for Canada.  Outside of the Excited States of America nobody on the entire planet uses M/D/Y!  In Canada we prefer D/M/Y because that is the order used both in British English "4th of July 1776" (Since GW and his friends all spoke British not American) and in French "le 4 Juillet 1776".

Comment: With something typed in and  you then  go Tools > Spelling what Text language is shown?

Comment: That dialog shows Text Language empty.  If I try to explicitly select Canadian Engish my request is ignored and the selection says [None]. How do I get Writer to pay attention to what I have specified?

Answer (score 6):

I had exact same issue and the default settings did not work for me. This worked for me. Even hunspell or myspell, as suggested by [resplin](https://askubuntu.com/users/84832/resplin), didn't work.

However adding this extension to Libre Office worked like charm: 
https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/english-dictionaries/

You'll need to go to Tools > Extension Manager > Add > {upload extension file}. Restart.

Comment: It was the restart that worked for me. tks

Answer (score 4):

Install the Hunspell library for Canadian English:

`sudo apt install hunspell-en-ca`

Then configure LibreOffice to use it:

Tools -> Options -> Language Settings -> Locale setting -> English (Canada)

Tools -> Options -> Language Settings -> Writing Aids -> Available language modules: Hunspell SpellChecker -> Edit -> Language: English (Canada)

Comment: It would be nice for Canadians to have the flexibility of UK English and American English loaded at the same time. After all it kind of is a hybrid country in language (plus other areas).

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix don't forget French Canadians :)

Comment: $ sudo apt install hunspell-en-ca
[sudo] password for jcobban: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
hunspell-en-ca is already the newest version (1:2017.08.24).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 45 not upgraded.

Comment: I would like to include a screenshot to show that I definitely HAVE installed and activated canadian english but Writer is NOT doing any spell checking.